# Group into a dictionary of elements

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Hi I have a list of element of class type class1 as show below. How do I group them into a

`Dictionary<int,List<SampleClass>>` based on the groupID

```
class SampleClass
{
   public int groupID;
   public string someData;
 }
```

I have done this way:

```
var t =(from data in datas group data by data.groupID into dataGroups select dataGroups).ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.ToList()[0].groupID, gdc => gdc.ToList());
```

Is there a better way of doing thiss

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It will be more efficient to replace:

```
gdc => gdc.ToList()[0].groupID
```

with:

```
gdc => gdc.Key
```

Other than that, it looks like I would have done.

Alternately, if you are okay with extension methods over LINQ (I personally prefer them), it can be shortened further still with:

```
var t = data.GroupBy(data => data.groupID).ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToList());
```