# Select object fields into a map using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am new to Linq. I have a list of objects which contain fields

```
userId, companyId
```

I need to assemble a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary Key= companyId
Dictionary Value = List(UserId that belong to companyId).
```

Can I achieve this using Linq, and if yes, in which way?

Comment: You want to `groupby' companyId,`ToDictionary`?

Comment: related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414813/group-into-a-dictionary-of-elements, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048431/linq-grouping-by-name-to-dictionarystring-listt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [.GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) `companyId` and directly convert the grouping to a Dictionary using the [.ToDictionary()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) extension method:

```
var dictPerCompany = 
    sourceList.GroupBy(src => src.companyId)
              .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Select(val => val.userId).ToList());
```

This generates a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`.

If you want to keep the information contained in the original class (for a better interpretation of the content, which has cost in memory though), you can convert the grouping to a
`Dictionary<int, List<yourSourceClass>>`.

```
var dictPerCompany = 
    sourceList.GroupBy(src => src.companyId)
              .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Select(val => val).ToList());
```

The conversion to Dictionary might not even be necessary. The type of choice depends on the destination.